# Connecting to Vertica database via pyodbc without odbc.ini on RHEL6

Tags: odbc, pyodbc, vertica, rhel6

I do not have the permission to edit the system-wide odbc.ini file, therefore I am searching for alternative ways to specify connection parameters towards Vertica.

I have unpacked the needed libraries to a certain location, and am attempting to create a connection string from my "custom" config file.

Is it possible to explicitly specify the path to the driver (and any other necessary parameters) when using pyodbc.connect?

Example intention (fails with the error below):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=path/to/libverticaodbc.so;...")
```

Error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Alternatively, is there another option to use odbc.ini files other than the ones at /etc/, e.g. through setting an environment variable?

Comment: OK I found that I can set the env variables ODBCINI and ODBCSYSINI, so will give that a try too.
But I am still interested in the answer to the original question.

Ref:http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/1.3.0/userguide/developers_guide/topics/odbc/install_config_odbc.html

Comment: BTW, here's a proper connect string: `cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Vertica};SERVER=192.168.123.456;PORT=1433;DATABASE=yourdb;UID=your_user;PWD=your_pw;')` You then need to add Vertica to your `.odbcinst.ini` in your home directory since you can't access the system-wide one with a path to the driver.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to avoid the use of ODBC driver to connect to Vertica . 
Vertica release  native driver for python ,  see attach full details and examples :

https://github.com/uber/vertica-python

I hope you will find it us-full

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but
1) I prefer not to depend on libraries in beta stage
2) It is not "released by Vertica" as far as I can see

Answer (score 1):

You can put a file called `.odbc.ini` in your home directory which will be for user specific ODBC settings.

http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to modify user's home directories, as this solution should be multi-user supportive and not affect any other environment parameters. (e.g. what if the user already has another .odbc.ini file in his/her home dir?)